# Why would someone want to wrap form elements inside of <div> tags?

Tags: html, css

For example. here is simple form (that I often use):

```
<form class="login">
      <input class="login_username" type="text" value="username"/>
      <input class="login_password" type="text" value="password"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

But I read some books, and see some of my friends often do:

```
<form class="login">
   <div class="login_username">
      <input class="login_input" type="text" value="username"/>
   </div>
   <div class="login_password">
      <input class="login_password" type="text" value="password"/>
   </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

The difference is: they often wrap all components inside a div tag, and then assign its a class name (although inside div tag has only one component). I don't know which advantages when they do this.

Thanks :)

Comment: `div`is a 'natural' block element and this way you have more control with styling, although it can be easily achieved in different ways. It is more personal preference. I have done it both ways with an without and I prefer also to wrap it in a `div` or `p`.

Comment: Well, here is a thing, when you put input tag inside a div with class name to it, it just help us when we are validating the form, we can put error messages into closest div and then we can style it as per our requirements.

Comment: @VilasKumkar Very good point although appending an error message after/before your input is also an option.

Comment: designers can't have too many wrappers when it comes time to tweak the look. frameworks like bootstrap are notorious for this, but there's no real way around it unless you want to spend a lot of extra time writing custom CSS rules for existing patterns. you can use widgets to construct a lot of the boilerplate for you...

Comment: @Mikey Agreed!, but we can expect changes at any period of time, so if designer wants to show errors beside of input then putting input inside wrapper is the only way.

Comment: re: input error messages, while you can inject raw text before the input, it's much more consistent to have a div that you can inherit the max-width, overflow, etc on. in short, both work, but by pre-drawing the box, one can easy apply a consistent look to the errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[WHATWG: 4.10.1.1 Writing a form's user interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#writing-a-form's-user-interface)**

> Any form starts with a `form` element, inside which are placed the controls. Most controls are represented by the `input` element, which by default provides a text control. To label a control, the `label` element is used; the label text and the control itself go inside the `label` element. **Each part of a form is considered a paragraph**, and is typically separated from other parts using **`p`** elements. Putting this together, here is how one might ask for the customer's name:

```
<form>
  <p><label>Customer name: <input></label></p>
</form>
```

**[WAI: Forms > Grouping Controls](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/grouping/)**

> Grouping related form controls makes forms more understandable for all users, as related controls are easier to identify... In this example, the `div` element has `role=group` to indicate that the contained elements are members of a group and the `aria-labelledby` attribute references the id for text that will serve as the label for the group...

```
<div role="group" aria-labelledby="shipping_head">
    <div id="shipping_head">Shipping Address:</div>
    <div>
        <label for="shipping_name">
      <span class="visuallyhidden">Shipping </span>Name:
    </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="shipping_name" id="shipping_name">
    </div>
    […]
</div>
<div role="group" aria-labelledby="billing_head">
    <div id="billing_head">Billing Address:</div>
    <div>
        <label for="billing_name">
      <span class="visuallyhidden">Billing </span>Name:
    </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="billing_name" id="billing_name">
    </div>
    […]
</div>
```

It also recommends to use `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` elements. `<fieldset>` element provides a container for related form controls, and the `<legend>` element acts as a heading to identify the group.

Other than those, **Styling** and **Manipulating** are the main reasons for lots of developers.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends what you want to do.

Generally, the more layers you wrap around some other elements, the more flexibility you have if you want to create some effect with CSS and Javascript.

But it could just be a matter of preference.

In short, unless you have a reason, it makes little difference whether you will wrap your key elements, the < input >s in this case, in some other tag.

Comment: I think flexibility is the main reason.

Comment: Exactly.  It is for the stylesheet

Comment: can you tell me why more fexibility (for example creating effect) ? thanks :)

Comment: @hqt here is a fiddle I made to illustrate
https://jsfiddle.net/p25o1zof/1/

I used the same code as the one in the question, the 'friends' variation, not OPs  one.

It's a silly example, but it illustrates how if I had not wrapped the `<input>`s inside the divs I would not be able to achieve the effect when clicking on the grey divs

Answer (score 2):

It will mainly be for styling forms with CSS and potentially using some of the classes for Javascript hooks.

Comment: True but you may want to add styling around your elements, such as boxing and or arranging relevant elements together in columns, etc.

Comment: Yeah, he is right.  Using divs around form elements and the whole form makes it easier to use.  Let's say you have an outer wrapper and then you want to move the form somewhere else.  Now there is only one div to move rather than 3 input lines.