# What to use instead of the <br> tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/registration">
    <label for="alias">Alias:</label>    
    <input type="text" name="alias" id="alias">
    <br>
    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>    
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="registger">
</form>
```

It works fine, but the I have found out that `<br>` shouldn't be used for this purpose, as it is only intended to be used with text.

If I remove the `<br>`, then everything will be rendered on a single line, which I do not want.

What is the correct, most clean way to display name-input pairs in a form with CSS, like this:

```
Alias:  [__field__]
E-mail: [__field__]
  [SUBMIT BUTTON]
```

Comment: You can use float and margin.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29010868/483779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically would put the input inside of the label (so when you click the label, it focuses the input), and then tell the label to be `display: block;`.

So,

```
<form method="post" action="/registration">
  <label for="alias">
    Alias: <input type="text" name="alias" id="alias">
  </label>    
  <label for="email">
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  </label>
  <input type="button" value="registger">
</form>
```

Then do:

```
label[for], // just selects labels that have the "for" attribute.
input[type="button"] {
  display: block;
  // And a bottom margin for good measure :)
  margin: 0 0 10px; // shorthand for margin-bottom
}
```

And that should get you what you want.

Comment: I agree with nesting input's within label's, but this doesn't solve his problem of creating block content by default (with HTML alone / without CSS).

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik I re-read the OP to make sure I didn't misread, and it doesn't say anything about using HTML only. It just asks for an alternative to using a `br`.

Comment: You could easily make it html-only by putting the css into style attributes, anyway. This is probably the best answer here.

Comment: @ScottStubblefield A br works to create a line break without CSS, but a label alone does not. Use of br's in this way, however, is misuse, so he's in search of another solution that still accomplishes a tangible line break but isn't a br. (And even if he happened to not be in search of that, it's what he should be in search of.)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use divs, which will put the labels and inputs into their own block.

```
<form method="post" action="/registration">
    <div>
        <label for="alias">Alias:</label>    
        <input type="text" name="alias" id="alias">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>    
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="registger">
</form>
```

Comment: This definitely works, although div's convey no meaning, which is unfortunate.

Comment: Scott Stubblefield's answer is better, really.

Comment: @Jan Kyu Peblik: Agreed. I'd use paragraphs instead. (Or I guess lists as you suggest... though I've never seen anyone do that in the 20 years I've been writing HTML. Even the spec itself seems to prefer paragraphs.)

Comment: @BoltClock That is surprising to hear, but it's of course not important. :) What's important is that one puts forth greater than zero effort to choose appropriate elements. :D I would use a list myself, but if one views something as a paragraph in one's head, it is a fine choice.

Comment: @ChrisLear ...and no, your answer is better than Scott's. (Though mine is the best. You can tell because the vast majority has downvoted it the most, and the vast majority is always wrong. :D)

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik I agree with BoltClock, read this: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#writing-a-form's-user-interface

Comment: @Stickers You're missing the point, as there is no single perfect choice all the time. HTML is just not large enough for that. 'p' is a decent choice, but it means paragraph, and paragraph means nothing more than this: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paragraph

Comment: @Jan Kyu Peblik: HTML defines "paragraph" differently from its everyday usage. But we're seriously splitting hairs here. I agree with you that we're all spoiled for choice.

Comment: I think <p> is better than <div> for this. But I'll leave my original because, well, it's still probably what I'd use myself for the job in hand, even if it's not best.

Comment: @Stickers You're missing many points, actually. Including the bit where it says "This section is non-normative.". It is an example, & it is referring to an example. The purpose of HTML is to mark up data with meaning. What you consider the meaning to be is entirely up to you, the author.

Comment: Well, lists have defaults as well; that is of course a nice side effect of matching your data suitably to elements. But I think we are indeed in general agreement. :)

Answer (score -1):

You could use `div`s with corresponding CSS:

```css
.myFrm {
  width: 250px;
}

input[type=text] {
  float: right;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-group::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/registration">
  <div class="myFrm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="alias">Alias:</label>
      <input type="text" name="alias" id="alias">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="registger">
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use container divs around the label and input to group them or else make sure "display: block" is added to the label and input elements.

If you need the label to the left of the input then wrap both with a container div and to give you more control on the positioning you could float the label and input to the left or use flexbox.

Comment: Adding display:block to the label and input elements will stop them from appearing on the same line, which is not what's wanted

Answer (score -2):

I would just use a bit of css to do the trick. Give each of the labels a display:block;

```
label {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Then the input field will appear below the label, which isn't really what was wanted

Answer (score -2):

You ask:

> What is the correct, most clean way to display name-input pairs in a
>   form with CSS

I interpret your question to be related to matters of performance, code efficiency and maintainability. Since just changing the HTML structure does not address responsiveness in different view-ports, adding bits of CSS may have render blocking features but it does nevertheless makes your application ready for mobile responsiveness. This is how I see it:

```
form {
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input{
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
}

input[type=button]{
  top: 4%;
}
```

Note that for mobile viewports you may want to adjust the relative measures with media queries. So the question here is not about writing less code but the main requirements of the application.

[Get a plunk for this here](https://plnkr.co/edit/m4vREp6o1QPBapjvqjQK?p=preview)

Answer (score -5):

What you have there is a list.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/HTML_text_fundamentals#Lists

http://reisio.com/temp/form1.html

Comment: This is a comment, really, not an answer

Comment: You are both quite wrong. He should use a list instead of br's, and moreover it would defeat the purpose to tell him which particular element type of list, as the primary thing he needs to grasp is matching data to the best suited HTML element type by meaning. He has a list, he should find a list element to use, of which there are a number.

Comment: Let me give you an example of a list... as in a to do list for you... 1. look up the meaning of the word "list" 2. delete your comment answer

Comment: @musefan you one of the more humorous approaches to getting SO karma without being useful at all. :p

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik: I am helping you to understand your mistake... also, I didn't get 37k rep from commenting on peoples bad answers... it's all from helping people

Comment: Sure, sure. :)_

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18740761)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18740761)

Comment: @ChrisHarrison as already explained, the crux of the issue is not what code to use, but to understand how HTML elements are selected at all.

Comment: @DerekBrown Of course it does. (hey look I gave as much reason for why it does as you gave for why it doesn't)

Comment: @Jan Kyu Peblik your answer was deleted for two reasons; 1) it is a link-only answer.  You should try to summarize the main points of your links before you post. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)  2) This is more of a comment than an answer.  While the links may be a good starting place for the person asking, they don't directly provide an answer to his question.

Comment: @DerekBrown I appreciate you summarizing the reasoning of the actions of yourself and three other persons who have contributed no useful answer to the question posed. Try reading my answer. It's right. I already know it's right, and so will anyone else who knows the very basic purpose of HTML (it really isn't at all more complicated than that). I'd like you to know it's right, too, though, for no reason other than so you'll know it. :)

Comment: @Jan Kyu Peblik it's not about whether your answer is right or not, it is about the quality of your answer.  You should edit your answer to include the details of the articles that you link to.

Comment: @DerekBrown It's hard not to ask in response to such an assertion why an answer you don't consider necessarily incorrect should have been deleted, especially since it doesn't resemble a single other answer here given (which would make it the best answer, which of course it is). Instead of that I'll say: once again you have missed the point. There is no further explanation required than helping a person realize they need a conceptualization to match to an element type. If anybody has a problem with that, they can comment, they can edit. You had done neither, nor provided an answer of your own.

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik it's not about a dissertation.  You should just write a short blurb about lists, include the link and provide an in-line code example.  I suggest you read the documentation on how to answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: If your understanding of it is accurate, then I definitely have no interest reading something so daft.